# I can't pass parameters using react-navigation in react-native while navigating from a tab navigator screen to a stack navigator screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I think this is pretty straight forward when it comes to passing between screens of tab navigators but there seems to be a problem while trying to pass parameters from a tab navigator screen to a stack navigator screen in react-native using react-navigation.

I tried this:

```
onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('review', {
    aa1: 86,
    bb1: 'anything you want here',
    });
}}
```

And this:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'review', params: { aa1: 'x' }, }))}
```

as the onPress handler of my TouchableOpacity. None of them work. I can navigate but I can't get the params.

Below is how I try to get the parameters in the target stack navigator screen:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
//if a is not passed, No a is the default value.
const a = this.props.navigation.getParam('aa1', 'NO a');
const b = navigation.getParam('bb1', 'No b');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In what component you are trying to get `a` and `b` params ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was able to figure and solve the problem.
Problem was that name of the screen I was trying to navigate to and the name of the stack navigator (name of the stack navigator in the containing/parent tab navigator) that contained that screen was the same. And although navigation was working, the parameters were not being passed as I said in the problem description. Navigation was working because the screen that I was trying to navigate was set as the initial route in the containing stack navigator. Apparently, I was navigating and passing the parameters to the containing stack navigator. Once I changed the name of the stack navigator, the problem was solved.

Comment: I was struggling with that problem for a while now, your answer really helped me out a lot!!

Comment: I had the same problem and even though my screen name and stack navigator name were different, parameters weren't passed. But once I passed the screen name in the navigator props ( Even though it was the default / initial route ) , everything started working seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `navigation.push` instead of `navigation.navigate`.

Reference: [Oficial Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and i saw your own answer. The reason why this happens easily is that you are sending information to the stack, and not to the screens. As you can see in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators, when you want to pass parameters to another screen inside a stack you need to specify the stack, then the screen and then the parameters, just like that:

```
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Profile',
  params: { user: 'jane' },
});
```

To be honest you can just put the parameters right with the screen, as in:

```
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Profile',
  user: 'jane',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround the parameters with parentheses:

```
const FileOpen = ({route}) => {}
```

That worked for me.